# How to write this piece of code in php?

Tags: php

I have this line

```
foreach($giftmessage as $key=>$value) {

    $giftmessagearray['order_giftmessage_'.$key] = $value;
}
```

I want to add somewhere in the middle (I guess before the `$key` or the `$value`?) something that will print to my template.

I have tried this:

```
foreach($giftmessage as $key=>$value) {

    $customtext = "something to echo there";
    $giftmessagearray['order_giftmessage_'. $customtext .$key] = $value;
}
```

But it doesn't work, actually it breaks my query.

Comment: are those back-ticks just a typo?

Comment: @roullie My guess is it's a fail at trying to use SO's post syntax.

Comment: shouldn't you be change the value of the array not the key? the syntax is fine by the way you just need to explain the issue some more